# Need multiple copies of the same report in Crystal Report

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, sql-server-2008-r2

I am stuck with a peculiar problem. Here is my situation. I have an invoice designed in Crystal Report. I want to provide a feature wherein the user can print multiple copies. The statutory requirement is that every copy will have different title (for e.g. 1st copy may have "Original", 2nd may have "Duplicate for Transporter", etc.) The invoice already has 2 sub-reports (1st for the items and 2nd for tax details). Now I am stuck up as to how do I get multiple copies of the same report with different title. Tried using sub-report but according to crystal report, one cannot use sub-reports within sub-reports.

Request all to please help me some idea. I little new to crystal report. Thanks to all in advance.

My environment is VS 2010, Crystal Report v13, SQL Server 2008, .NET 4.0.

Comment: loop it 3 times then. :)

Comment: but i also want 3 different titles and not always i will print  multiple copies sometime 1 or some time 2

Comment: on my understanding, you mean all reports have the same data, but with different titles?

Comment: yes.Data will be same only title will change.

Comment: I have added an answer, try to check below. It is really easy you just have to add a "Text object" on your report

Answer (score 0):

If all data on your reports are the same and only the title is changed, you can set a **textObject** variable for your title on VB.
Here's how

```
 Dim T As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.TextObject

 T = cryRpt.ReportDefinition.Sections(1).ReportObjects("yourTextObjectFromXtalReport")
 T.Text = "Your Title"
```

All you have to do is to set conditions on your program if you want to have multiple reports.

You can also print crystal reports programmatically by following [this](http://vb.net-informations.com/crystal-report/vb.net_crystal_report_export_pdf.htm).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a parameter Title and set the value each time you are printing the report. Drag the parameter to the report in order to have it printed